# data submitted into database if the informations are invalid using jquery,Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to Jquery and ajax.I want to check if mail id is already exist in database. So I use Ajax to check email is exist or not. I check this condition during submitting a form, so I use onSubmit event.
when I enter submit button the above condition is checked and then inserted into database.but If condition fails that email also inserted into database. 
what is the error? I cannot find this error please help me!
 my html code is:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>Registration</h3>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action = "" onSubmit=" return checkmail();">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Firstname</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Firstname" name="fname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Lastname</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Lastname"name="lname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" >
                                <span id="check"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password" name="pass" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">re-Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repass" placeholder="re-Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Mobile no</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" placeholder="Mobile no" name="phone">
                            </div>
                            <h6 id="aaa"></h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address1</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address1" name="addr1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address2</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address2(optional)"name="addr2"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >Country</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Country" name="country">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >State</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="State" name="state">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >City</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="City" name="city">
                            </div>
                        </div>                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Zipcode</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="EX:456322" name="zip" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Register">                      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my Jquery function is

```
   function checkmail(){
                var mail= $('#email').val();
                if(mail ==""){
                    $("#email").focus();
                    alert("Enter mail id");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url :'check.php',
                        data: {emailid:mail},
                        success: function(responseText){
                            $("#check").html(responseText);
                            if(responseText != 1) { // if the response is 1 
                                $("#check").html("Available!"); 
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                // else blank response                                          
                                $("#email").focus();
                                $("#check").html("Email are already exist.");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
    </script>
```

check.php

```
  <?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','registration');            //set coonection to db
    $mail = $_POST['emailid'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "select email from user where email='".$mail."' ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        echo '1';                                                       // if mail exist
    }



?>
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action = "" onSubmit="checkmail()">
```

And put the script right after body tag starts.

I will recommend you to do this from jquery

```
$("#form-id").on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

// Validation for data
});
```

Comment: but it insert a data into database if the mail is already exists

Comment: try this in success function
if(responseText != '1') instead of if(responseText != 1)
returned echo is a string.

Answer (score 0):

use below code with few modification.

**The HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>Registration</h3>
                    <form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Firstname</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Firstname" name="fname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Lastname</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Lastname"name="lname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" >
                                <span id="check"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password" name="pass" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">re-Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repass" placeholder="re-Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Mobile no</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" placeholder="Mobile no" name="phone">
                            </div>
                            <h6 id="aaa"></h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address1</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address1" name="addr1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address2</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address2(optional)"name="addr2"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >Country</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Country" name="country">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >State</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="State" name="state">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >City</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="City" name="city">
                            </div>
                        </div>                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Zipcode</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="EX:456322" name="zip" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="button" onClick="checkmail();" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Register">                      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
function checkmail(){
                var mail= $('#email').val();
                if(mail ==""){
                    $("#email").focus();
                    alert("Enter mail id");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url :'check.php',
                        data: {emailid:mail},
                        success: function(responseText){
                            $("#check").html(responseText);
                            if(responseText != 1) { // if the response is 1 
                                $("#check").html("Available!"); 
                                $("#myForm").submit();
                            }
                            else {
                                // else blank response                                          
                                $("#email").focus();
                                $("#check").html("Email are already exist.");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Change the id of form accordingly, which kept as **myForm**

Comment: This code checks valid or not but if email is available then doesn't insert into database.

Comment: `$("#myForm").submit()` This piece of code will submit the form, same way as submitting earlier. Nothing else

Comment: I try this but it  doesn't insert a data into the database if the mail is available